# ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception) OpenSSL is not available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, openssl

I get this openssl error when trying to install/update any gem, although I have openSSL installed through `brew install openssl`.

This can be frustrating but there is a way to address this problem.

Comment: "The latest version of OSX has deprecated openSSL.". Nope. OSX has not shipped with openSSL for many years (5?) as Apple has had reservations about a number of issues and prefers to provide their own implementation.

Comment: Thanks for catching that @max . Removed it.

Answer (score 8):

To address this problem, you need to:

1. Install openssl: `brew install openssl`
2. Using whatever package manager you use for ruby (rbenv, rvm, frum), reinstall the ruby version you need to work with, using the cli option for specifying the openssl directory to be used by the ruby version being installed.

For rvm that means:

```
rvm reinstall 2.3.0 --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl`
```

For frum:

```
frum uninstall <ruby version>
frum install <ruby version> --with-openssl-dir=<ssl_dir> # Specify the OpenSSL directory
```

This guide was geared towards MacOS. Similarly, you should reinstall ruby with the right cli options on whichever operating system you are using.

Comment: The option for ram reinstall is `--with-openssl-dir=\`brew --prefix openssl\``.

Comment: This works, but it looks like your two separate dashes `--` combined to form an em dash (—) which causes this to fail if you just copy paste and run

Comment: Edited to try to fix the em dash issue above.